# I am running a java based game on netbeans . How do I figure out the data flow in it?

Tags: java, netbeans

How do I inspect the data flow when I run the game in netbeans IDE so that I can make changes to the code to play with the data ?

Answer (score 0):

You can debug your application line by line. By pressing `F7` key.

More info http://netbeans.org/features/java/debugger.html

Answer (score 0):

You could log the crucial steps and data and then examine the log file against your source. Netbeans IDE comes with a magnificent debugger. It will show you exactly how your program runs and displays the values of your variables in tooltips.